# Wake Up iOS App with BLE Advertisment

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to create an app, that is woken up when the device receives a certain BLE advertisment (not iBeacon format). Is this possible with the iOS Core-Bluetooth API?

In the Apple documentation for the Bluetooth-Central role is written:

> In addition, the system wakes up your app when any of the CBCentralManagerDelegate or CBPeripheralDelegate delegate methods are invoked, allowing your app to handle important central role events, such as when a **connection is established** or **torn down**, when a peripheral sends **updated characteristic values**, and when a **central manager’s state changes**.

It seems that the documentation describes only events for connected bluetooth devices. In my case a non-connectable BLE device is used, that only sends BLE advertisment packages.

I found this [SO](http://n%20addition,%20the%20system%20wakes%20up%20your%20app%20when%20any%20of%20the%20CBCentralManagerDelegate%20or%20CBPeripheralDelegate%20delegate%20methods%20are%20invoked,%20allowing%20your%20app%20to%20handle%20important%20central%20role%20events,%20such%20as%20when%20a%20connection%20is%20established%20or%20torn%20down,%20when%20a%20peripheral%20sends%20updated%20characteristic%20values,%20and%20when%20a%20central%20manager%E2%80%99s%20state%20changes.) post but there is no clear solution described.

Comment: You can scan for peripherals in the background - although as the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide states, discovery rate may be slower.

Comment: Does the app require to run in the background for scanning or is it a similar principle as with the beacon monitoring where the system will wake the app even when it is not running when a peripheral is found?

Comment: It is similar, but a little different.  If your app is terminated it will only be restarted if you implement state restoration - this is covered in the background section of the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide

Comment: Ok thank you. I will have a deeper look into the state restoration.
Do you have any expirience regarding the reliability?